# Laravel htaccess, redirect url if find /en

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

My old url

```
www.example.com/cn/news
www.example.com/cn/event
```

I want to if user enter /cn url Laravel will redirect into this url

```
www.example.com/en/news
www.example.com/en/event
```

here is my laravel .htaccess in root folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I try this one but it doest work

```
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /cn [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1/en/%2/? [L,R=301]
```

**UPDATE**

now  .htaccess  look like this but still didnt work 
    
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^cn/(.*)$ en/$1 [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^cn/?(.*)$ en/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This rule alone should work.

Match a cn prefix with an optional / and capture all characters after the /.